# Save image to folder and image path to database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an application called *Profiler* to store some people's profiles, and will use a database to store the profile photo's path.

This is my `FindPhoto` button (to upload the profile photo):

```
private void btnFindPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ofdFindPhoto.Title = "Select a Photo ";
    ofdFindPhoto.InitialDirectory = @"D:\Desktop";
    ofdFindPhoto.FileName = "";
    ofdFindPhoto.Filter = "JPEG Image|*.jpg|GIF Image|*.gif|PNG Image|*.png|BMP Image|*.bmp";
    ofdFindPhoto.Multiselect = false;
    if (ofdFindPhoto.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) { return; }

    // Show the recently uploaded photo on profile
    picProfilePhoto.ImageLocation = ofdFindPhoto.FileName;
}
```

When the user clicks the button to save the profile, I get the txtName.Text, txtPhone.Text, txtDescription.Text and photo path to save to the database.  I want to use something like this to save the photo path:

```
string photoPath = Application.StartupPath + @"\Photos\" + txtName.Text +
                   Path.GetExtension(ofdFindPhoto.FileName);
```

This should generate some path like:

> Drive:\InstalledPath\Profiler\Username.jpg (or whatever extension)

In short, I need to place a folder inside the application's root, but this folder should be created on install or first run (preferably that I can use on debug, too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(!Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Photos"))
         Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + @"\Photos");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in program.cs.It checks for folder when the application in opened

```
          if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Profiles"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Profiles");

            }
     Application.Run(new form1());
```

Comment: The slashes in your file paths should be backslashes.

Comment: @FabianBigler thanks for pointing that.Works without slashes too